# Finding $x+y$ given that $(2^{28}-1)$ is divisible by $x,y$ and between $120 ,130$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The number $(2^{28}-1)$ is divisible by $x,y$.If each of  $x,y$ is between $120 ,130$ .How to find $x+y$

Comment: You probably have to specify that $x, y$ are distinct, in order to have a unique answer. Otherwise we could have $x+y=127+127, 127+129, 129+129$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the decomposition $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ you can factorize $(2^{28}-1)$ as
$$
  2^{28}-1
=
  (2^{14}+1)(2^{14}-1)
=
  (2^{14}+1)(2^7+1)(2^7-1)
$$
Now, $2^7+1=129$ and $2^7-1=127$...

Comment: How quickly can you be sure that $2^{14}+1$ doesn't have any divisors within the given range?  Note that it's not prime, and its divisors come _very_ close (113 and 145 both divide it)...

Comment: You are right, mine was just a hint as the three dots at the end suggest. Anyway, assuming there is only a couple of such distinct $x,y$ as the question seems to imply, once you find one you can end it there. Otherwise I agree a bit more reasoning is necessary. @MathGems' method seems a very elegant way to remove all doubt.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $$2^{28}-1=\left(2^{14}-1\right)\left(2^{14}+1\right)=\left(2^7-1\right)\left(2^7+1\right)\left(2^{14}+1\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using general techniques that do not require use of special factorization formulas (so it may work more widely). Suppose $\rm\:f,g\in \Bbb Z[x]\:$ are polynomials with integer coefficients and suppose that we are searching for divisors of $\rm\:f(g(a))\:$ near $\rm\:g(a),\:$ say $\rm\:g(a)-n\:$ for small $\rm\:n.\:$ Testing such candidate divisors is especially simple by modular arithmetic since

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm\:mod\ g(a)-n\!:\,\ g(a)\equiv n\:\Rightarrow\:f(g(a))\equiv f(n)\\  \\
\rm\Rightarrow\ \ g(a)-n\mid f(g(a))\iff g(a)-n\mid f(n)\end{eqnarray}$$

We seek divisors of $\rm\:(2^7)^4\!-\!1\:$ near $\,2^7\!=128,\:$ say $\rm\:2^7\!-n \in [120,130].\,$ Thus, as above

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} mod\ 2^7\!-n\!:\,\ 2^7\equiv n\:\Rightarrow\: (2^7)^4\!-1\equiv n^4-1\\ 
\\
\rm \Rightarrow\ \ 2^7\!-n\mid 2^{28}\!-1\iff \color{#C00}{2^7\!-n\mid n^4\!-1}\end{eqnarray}$$

Applying this $\rm\color{#C00}{test}$ to the necessarily odd divisors in the interval $[120,130]$ yields

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
\rm \color{#C00}{128\!-n}&\: \mid\,&\rm \color{#C00}{n^4\!-1} \\
\hline
11^2=121&\: \nmid\,&7^4\!-1 = 49\cdot 51\rm\ \ by\ \ 11\nmid 49,51\\
3\cdot 41=123&\: \nmid\,&5^4\!-1 = 24\cdot 25\rm \ \ by\ \ 41\nmid 24,25\\
5^3=125&\:\nmid\,&3^4\!-1 = \ \ 8\cdot 9\ \ \rm \ \ by\ \ \ \ 5\nmid 8,9\\
    \color{#0A0}{127}&\mid&1^4\!-1 =\ 0\\
    \color{#0A0}{129}&\mid&\! (-1)^4\!-1 =\ 0\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Thus the only divisors of $\,2^{28}\!-1\,$ in the interval $\,[120,130]\,$ are $\,\color{#0A0}{127,129}.$ Once one knows the above technique, testing the divisors as above is very fast, about a  half minute of mental arithmetic. As such, it is often more efficient to do this test than to search for special factorizations or other innate structure (different from than the *compositional* structure that this method employs).